# Search for substrings / patterns in specific order, regexp? sql mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

In my MySQL i want to look for characters in a specific ORDER...

the following code doesn't care how 'o' 'l' 'd' appear... so words containing those characters would be matched...

I'm only interested in doing the match if 'o' appears first, 'l' second and 'd' third.

Alternatives to REGEXP are also welcome!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(col) 
FROM tab 
WHERE col REGEXP 'o'
AND col REGEXP 'l'
AND col REGEXP 'd'
GROUP BY col
ORDER BY col DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT isn't a function DISTINCT should be used as `SELECT DISTINCT col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following

```
SELECT col 
FROM tab 
WHERE col like "%o%l%d%"
ORDER BY col DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT isn't a function DISTINCT should be used as `SELECT DISTINCT col`

Comment: You are right, good catch Raymond. I updated the query string.

Comment: Ricardo, yes the % are wildcards in the like statement.

Comment: Don't do _both_ `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  And do neither if `col` is not duplicated.

Comment: Good catch Rick James